# uniform value from a range of numbers?

Tags: random, distribution, uniform, non-uniform-distribution

how do you randomly select a uniform value from a range of numbers?

i am trying to select a uniform value from a range of numbers like 1-10, randomly. please help me how to do it

what is the enum in C++ ?
purpose of #define ?

thanks

regards

Cash

Comment: Are you just asking for how to do random number generation, or are you talking about uniform distribution?

Comment: there is a range of numbers for example 1-10 and i want to randomly select a uniform value out of this range.